# How to show $\Vert A \Vert_p \le \max|a_{ij}| \Vert \mathbb{1} \Vert_p$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

### Problem

> Show $\Vert A \Vert_p \le \max|a_{ij}| \Vert \mathbb{1} \Vert_p$, where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, $\mathbb{1}$: $(m \times n)$ matrix with all the elements 1, and $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes the matrix p-norm .

---

### Try

We have

$$
\Vert A \Vert_p = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_p = 1} \left\Vert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} x_k \right\Vert_p
$$

Let $a_i = [a_{i1}, \cdots, a_{in}]^T$ and $\xi_i = a_i/\Vert a_i \Vert_p$.

When $p=2$, it is clear that $\Vert A \Vert_p = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_p = 1} \left\Vert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} x_k \right\Vert_p = \max_{1 \le i \le n} \left< a_i, \xi_i\right>$, since for each fixed $i$, the best of $\sup_{\Vert x \Vert_p = 1} \left\Vert \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} x_k \right\Vert_p$ is attained by projecting $a_i$ to $\xi_i$.

However, I'm not sure I am allowed to do similarly for any $p \in [1, \infty]$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $||A||_p$

Comment: @DionelJaime Thank you for pointing out, I have edited to specify it.

Comment: Consider this example: let $m$ be big, $x=[1, 1, ..., 1]^T$, and $A$ be the $m\times n$ matrix withh all entries $\frac 1n$. Then $Ax=[1, ..., 1]^T$ with $m$ many $1$'s. Thus $\|x\|_p=\sqrt[p]{n}$. But $\|Ax\|_p=\sqrt[p]{m}$ which can be large compare with $\|x\|_p$ if $m$ is large.

Comment: @YuDing Thanks, I have misunderstood the original problem. Edited.